# django-rest-framework JSON POST, request.data throws cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm tring to build a REST api using Django-REST-Framework and python 3.6, But facing an issue with POST requests

I can successfully POST json data using postman to an endpoint with content-type set to "application/json" and read it as a dict by doing `request.data`. This works if I start the server by running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

However, When I'm debugging on Visual Studio Code , Django's standard HttpRequest object does not get overridden by django-rest-framework's enhanced Request object and raises `RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")`

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def customers(request):    
    received_data = request.data
```

Middlewares defined in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Installed apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_mysql',

    'api',
    'installer',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',

    'django_celery_beat',
]
```

VS code's launch.json

```
      {
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "/Users/bharath/miniconda3/envs/shopify/bin/python",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/backend/manage.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/backend",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading",
                  "--no-color"
            ],
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
        },
```